# Getting each levels of data of complex nested JSON using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying below code to get each levels of data in a complex JSON data and trying to display on page as below

[image]

**Level one** - Welcome
**Level Two** - Home, Menu1 ,Menu2 ...
**Level Three** - Page1, Page2 , Page for parent level -Home
**Level Four** - Page11, Page12 forparent level Page 1,
          similarly           Page21, Page22 forparent level Page 2

JSON:

```
{
    "type": "DIV",
    "content": [{
        "type": "H1",
        "content": ["Welcome"]
    }, {
        "type": "HEADER",
        "content": ["\n            ", {
            "type": "DIV",
            "content": ["\n                ", {
                "type": "NAV",
                "content": [{
                    "type": "DIV",
                    "content": ["\n                                                    ", {
                        "type": "H3",
                        "content": ["Home"]
                    }, {
                        "type": "UL",
                        "content": [{
                            "type": "LI",
                            "content": [{
                                    "type": "A",
                                    "content": ["Page1"],
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "id": "page1",
                                        "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                        "tabindex": "0",
                                        "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page1.html",
                                        "aria-label": "Page1",
                                        "role": "treeitem",
                                        "aria-setsize": "23",
                                        "aria-posinset": "1",
                                        "aria-level": "1"
                                    }
                                },


                                {
                                    "type": "UL",
                                    "content": [{
                                        "type": "LI",
                                        "content": [{
                                            "type": "A",
                                            "content": ["Page11"],
                                            "attributes": {
                                                "id": "page1",
                                                "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                                "tabindex": "0",
                                                "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page11.html",
                                                "aria-label": "Page12",
                                                "role": "treeitem",
                                                "aria-setsize": "23",
                                                "aria-posinset": "11",
                                                "aria-level": "1"
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }, {
                                        "type": "LI",
                                        "content": [{
                                            "type": "A",
                                            "content": ["Page12"],
                                            "attributes": {
                                                "id": "page12",
                                                "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                                "tabindex": "0",
                                                "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page12.html",
                                                "aria-label": "Page1",
                                                "role": "treeitem",
                                                "aria-setsize": "23",
                                                "aria-posinset": "12",
                                                "aria-level": "1"
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }






                            ]
                        }, {
                            "type": "LI",
                            "content": [{
                                "type": "A",
                                "content": ["Page2"],
                                "attributes": {
                                    "id": "page2",
                                    "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                    "tabindex": "0",
                                    "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page2.html",
                                    "aria-label": "Page2",
                                    "role": "treeitem",
                                    "aria-setsize": "23",
                                    "aria-posinset": "1",
                                    "aria-level": "2"
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "type": "LI",
                            "content": [{
                                "type": "A",
                                "content": ["Page3"],
                                "attributes": {
                                    "id": "page3",
                                    "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                    "tabindex": "0",
                                    "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page3.html",
                                    "aria-label": "Page3",
                                    "role": "treeitem",
                                    "aria-setsize": "23",
                                    "aria-posinset": "1",
                                    "aria-level": "3"
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }, {
                    "type": "DIV",
                    "content": ["\n                                                    ", {
                        "type": "H3",
                        "content": ["Menu1"]
                    }, {
                        "type": "UL",
                        "content": [{
                            "type": "LI",
                            "content": [{
                                "type": "A",
                                "content": ["menuPage1"],
                                "attributes": {
                                    "id": "menuPage1",
                                    "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                    "tabindex": "0",
                                    "href": "https://zzzzzz/menu1.html",
                                    "aria-label": "Page1",
                                    "role": "treeitem",
                                    "aria-setsize": "23",
                                    "aria-posinset": "1",
                                    "aria-level": "1"
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "type": "LI",
                            "content": [{
                                "type": "A",
                                "content": ["menuPage2"],
                                "attributes": {
                                    "id": "menuPage2",
                                    "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                    "tabindex": "0",
                                    "href": "https://zzzzzz/menu2.html",
                                    "aria-label": "menuPage2",
                                    "role": "treeitem",
                                    "aria-setsize": "23",
                                    "aria-posinset": "1",
                                    "aria-level": "2"
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "type": "LI",
                            "content": [{
                                "type": "A",
                                "content": ["menuPage3"],
                                "attributes": {
                                    "id": "menuPage3",
                                    "class": "tertiaryLink",
                                    "tabindex": "0",
                                    "href": "https://zzzzzz/menu3.html",
                                    "aria-label": "menuPage3",
                                    "role": "treeitem",
                                    "aria-setsize": "23",
                                    "aria-posinset": "1",
                                    "aria-level": "3"
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I tried using the recursive jquery to fetch but couldn't get all levels

Codepen URL for reference:

http://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/oZWGpL

Codepen for expected HTML is close to mentioned below
https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/YZVgzr

Comment: Note, the `attributes` at `type:"A"` have duplicate `id` attribute `"page1"`

Comment: Why are you using JSON to transport information that is clearly better described as an HTML structure?

Comment: Can you include expected resulting `html` at Question?

Comment: @gyre, the mentioned JSON structure is obtained using jsTree and then from the obtained JSON, I am trying to convert it as a sitemap

Answer (score 0):

Needs more `jQuery()`. Use `jQuery(html, attributes)`. Note, not certain if `javascript` at stacksnippets renders exact expected `html`; expected `html` does not appear at Question, though you should be able to emulate pattern to achieve exact expected result. Substituted duplicate `id` at `"page1"` for `"page11"`, incremented `tabindex` value of each `"A"` type, or `<a>` element.

The approach should use similar amount of code and lines to append `html` content to `document`, rather than the laborious task of parsing nested arrays, where elements of array could be both string and object.

```js
$("#c2")
  .append(
    $("<DIV>", {
      "html": $("<H1>", {
        "html": "Welcome"
      })
    }),
    $("<HEADER>", {
      "html": "\n",
      "append": $("<DIV>", {
        "html": "\n",
        "append": $("<NAV>", {
          "html": $("<DIV>", {
            "html": "\n",
            "append": $("<H3>", {
              "html": "Home"
            })
          })
        })
      })
    }),
    $("<UL>", {
      "html": $("<LI>", {
        "html": $("<A>", {
          "html": "Page1",
          "id": "page1",
          "class": "tertiaryLink",
          "tabindex": "0",
          "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page1.html",
          "aria-label": "Page1",
          "role": "treeitem",
          "aria-setsize": "23",
          "aria-posinset": "1",
          "aria-level": "1"
        })
      })
    }),
    $("<UL>", {
      "html": $("<LI>", {
        "html": $("<A>", {
          "html": "Page11",
          "id": "page11",
          "class": "tertiaryLink",
          "tabindex": "1",
          "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page1.html",
          "aria-label": "Page1",
          "role": "treeitem",
          "aria-setsize": "23",
          "aria-posinset": "11",
          "aria-level": "1"
        })
      })
    }),
    $("<UL>", {
      "html": $("<LI>", {
        "html": $("<A>", {
          "html": "Page12",
          "id": "page12",
          "class": "tertiaryLink",
          "tabindex": "2",
          "href": "https://zzzzzz/Page11.html",
          "aria-label": "Page11",
          "role": "treeitem",
          "aria-setsize": "23",
          "aria-posinset": "12",
          "aria-level": "1"
        })
      })
    }),
    $("<DIV>", {
      "html": $("<H3>", {
        "html": "Welcome"
      })
    }),
    $("<UL>", {
      "html": $("<LI>", {
        "html": $("<A>", {
          "html": "menuPage1",
          "id": "menuPage1",
          "class": "tertiaryLink",
          "tabindex": "3",
          "href": "https://zzzzzz/menu1.html",
          "aria-label": "Page1",
          "role": "treeitem",
          "aria-setsize": "23",
          "aria-posinset": "1",
          "aria-level": "1"
        })
      })
    }),
    $("<UL>", {
      "html": $("<LI>", {
        "html": $("<A>", {
          "html": "menuPage2",
          "id": "menuPage2",
          "class": "tertiaryLink",
          "tabindex": "4",
          "href": "https://zzzzzz/menu2.html",
          "aria-label": "Page1",
          "role": "treeitem",
          "aria-setsize": "23",
          "aria-posinset": "1",
          "aria-level": "2"
        })
      })
    }),
    $("<UL>", {
      "html": $("<LI>", {
        "html": $("<A>", {
          "html": "menuPage3",
          "id": "menuPage3",
          "class": "tertiaryLink",
          "tabindex": "5",
          "href": "https://zzzzzz/menu1.html",
          "aria-label": "Page1",
          "role": "treeitem",
          "aria-setsize": "23",
          "aria-posinset": "1",
          "aria-level": "1"
        })
      })
    })
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="c2"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to convert nested json to html

Comment: @divyareddy Yes, you can format or parse `JSON` to be parameters passed to `jQuery(html, attributes)` at single call.

Comment: When parsing substitute `$("<type>", {html, attributes})` `html`, `append` for `content` property, or adjust `JSON` to be formatted for parameter to `jQuery()`

Comment: @divyareddy The first property of `content` possibly being a new line character,  with next property being an object is an interesting data structure to try to parse.

Comment: the JSON structure mentioned is obtained using jsTree.js from which I am trying to create sitemap as mentioned in the screenshot

Comment: Have not tried jsTree.js. What is expected resulting HTML?

Comment: ,expected html which I am trying is something as below
https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/YZVgzr

Comment: How can `JSON` at  Question produce `html` at codepen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137891/discussion-between-divya-reddy-and-guest271314).